# MySql Search With Special Character

Tags: php, mysql

I searching records from database using `MySql` as -

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE col LIKE '%myvalue%';
```

This is working fine and showing all the records having `myvalue`.

Now the problem is i have some records like `my'value`, `myva'lue`, `myval-ue` and `my-value` And also want to include these records in search. Also when i search for `my'value` then it should show `myvalue` and `my-value`.

How to achieve this? Any Help. Is it possible to do using `LIKE` operator?

Comment: ohh you have data as `myval-ue` too? Just curious, how did data get inserted like this in DB??

Comment: this is just an example.

Comment: I think, you will need to deal with this in php only... I don't think mysql could help you. **Hint: In php use regexp and replace special character with null and match for myvalue**

Comment: Can you please show me some example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this...

**PHP Part**

```
$term = str_replace('-','',str_replace(',', '', str_replace('\'', '', $term)));
```

**MySql Part**

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE ((REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(col, '\'', ''), ',', ''), '-', '') LIKE "%$term%") 
OR (col LIKE "%$term%"));
```

See this **[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10476/4)**.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using PHP you should do the following, if someone uses your search:

1. Get the search-term via $_POST
2. Remove all special characters from the search-term (`my'value` becomes `myvalue`)
3. Replace the search term with MySQL wildcards (`myvalue` becomes `%m%y%v%a%l%u%e%`)
4. Execute `SELECT * FROM tab WHERE col LIKE '%m%y%v%a%l%u%e%'`

Any of the other solutions will not match all your requirements.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20f811/2

Comment: can you take a look at [**this**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10476/1). Especially last row

Comment: @FahimParkar Your answer has that same issue.

Comment: @GolezTrol : Hence I told OP to do it at PHP end... Edit 2

Comment: Assuming that the description above is accurate (IE, only one special character), wouldn't _m_y_v_a_l_u_e_
be a better choice than "%m%y%v%a%l%u%e%"? The first will return every string described in the question, but will not match strings like "myniftyvalue" or "my__value", so you'll retrieve fewer unwanted results with your statement. (Edit: Curse the autoformatter. My string above starts and ends with an underscore, but I can't figure out how to escape the underscores in a comment)

Comment: @FahimParkar You are right, but AshwiniAgarwal didn't ask for `mysomething elsevalue`.
@AmericanUmlaut `%m_y_v_a_l_u_e%` wouldn't match `myvalue`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE col LIKE '%myvalue%' OR col LIKE '%my_value%'
```

The underscore `_` is a single character wildcard.

Comment: how this query will give result as `my'value`?

Comment: but the special character an be any where in the value. How do i know where to put `_`?

Comment: @FahimParkar It will. Like I said, the underscore is a wildcard, just as `%`.

Comment: @AshwiniAgarwal That's a different story then. It's hard to tell what exactly you need by looking at these fictive data. I think the best way would be to use `replace` and then like. `WHERE replace(replace(col, '\'', ''), '-', '') LIKE '%myvalue%'`. But you would need a replace for each of those characters that can occur in the string. Some databases have the `translate` function, which would be more convenient, but I think it doesn't exist in MySQL.

Comment: @GolezTrol : see OP updated question. possible data can be `my'value`, `myva'lue`, `myval-ue` and `my-value`

Comment: @FahimParkar I already commented to that as well. My reply to you was that my query *will* match the example you gave. I suggest you do some reading and trying yourself before placing such comments. It is your answer that is less perfect, because it would match `ohmyothernormaltextvalue` as well, which has normal text instead of special characters between the two parts of the search query.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE col LIKE 'my%' OR col LIKE '%value'
```

this will check `col` should start with my and end with value.

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a7c4/4)

---

### Edit 1

As there can be any special character and regexp don't work with MySQL, I would suggest you to do what you want to achieve in PHP by replacing special character by null and then matching the string with myvalue.

Hope this helps you.

---

### Edit 2

I don't know php exactly, but can tell you what to do little bit.

```
mysql = "SELECT id, col FROM tab WHERE col LIKE '%my%' OR col LIKE '%value%'";
rs = mysql.execute();
String newString = "";
while (rs.next()) {
    newString = rs.getString(2);
    newString = new string after replacing special characters using regexp
    if (newString.equals("myvalue")) {
        // your code here..... this is place what you wanted.
    }
}
```